# Is normative economic planning value-neutral or value-based?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-terms

I'm really confused with the meaning of the terms 'normative planning' and 'system planning'. [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/12/difference-between-positive-normative-economics.asp) says "normative economics is subjective and value-based". On the other hand, many other sites say normative planning is value-neutral, while system planning is value-based.

As far as economic planning is concerned, which one is value-neutral? - System planning or normative planning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to mention that while it is very accessible, Investopedia is (IMO) a poor source that sometimes contains mistakes and muddles concepts.

---

From [Foundations for Normative Planning by Klosterman](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232967550_The_Foundations_of_Normative_Planning)

> Most radical have been the calls by Friedmann
> (1966), Faludi (1973), and others for “normative”
> planning in which planners subject both the ends and
> means of public policy to rational consideration. These
> proposals are of particular interest because they suggest that the planning profession can combine scientific analysis with reform and change and thus be true
> to both of its intellectual roots. 
> However, none of the calls for normative planning
> has outlined the procedures by which planners are to
> rationally evaluate public policy ends. More fundamentally, they have not developed the logical foundation for rational consideration of ethical issues in
> public policy-an activity which runs counter to
> some of the most fundamental and widely shared
> assumptions of the positive social sciences.

Thus normative planning purports to be value-netrual, but in practice this seems to be impossible. Indeed, economic planning is usually about

1. what goal to reach (there are several metrics to consider, usually with trade-offs)
2. how to reach that goal in terms of efficiency, probability, etc.

The first step simply cannot be value-neutral. See the vast literature on Social Choice or the corresponding chapter in microeconomics textbooks. 
Even the second step is unlikely to be value-neutral in practice. Some believe that awarding a contract to the lowest bidder fulfilling a certain set of criteria is value-neutral, but who these probable bidders are is usually well-known, and awarding contracts to them may further inequality.

---

I am not that familiar with "System planning" - this seems to be an engineering term -, so it would be nice to have someone else elaborate on this. I suspect that the difficulties outlined above persist: one hides values in the choice of the goal function of the planning problem.

Comment: Thanks. That made it clear!